# Why my MVC 3 Form not getting posted to the right controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view which renders just fine through Index() action.
Basically I read from DB and load into my model.

When user fills out or changes values and hit Submit, I want to form to be posted to a different action on same controller.

But the form gets submitted to the default index() action.

Ultimate goal is to keep the user on the same page, but show a result of the submit.

Here are my codes:

Area registration to register the route:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Test",
                "app/test/{Id}",
                new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" }
            );
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string rk, string g){
  TestModel model = new TestModel();
  //Now read from DB & populate the model
  return View(model);  
}
```

This is the action where I want submit for to be posted:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(TestModel model)
{
    model = new TestModel();
    model.Status = "Form Posted!";

    return View("Index", model);
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { id="frmUpdate"}))
{
   //My form fields get populated by model
   <button type="submit" id="btnUpdate" onclick="return ValidateAndSubmit(this.id, 'result_label');">Update</button>
}
```

JS Interceptor on submit click:

```
function ValidateAndSubmit(b, l) {
        //do validation before submit
        if (AnyFieldNotValid) { alert('failed'); return false; }
        else {
            $("#frmUpdate").submit();
        }        
    }
```

Anything I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I can't do an $.ajax() post as I have a recaptcha on the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be  2 routes like this to solve the 404:

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "Test1",
            "app/test/{Id}",
            new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "Test2",
            "app/test/{action}",
            new { controller = "Test", action = "Update" }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your route does not allow for an action parameter, so anything which is posted to that controller will be routed to the default action you have supplied, which is `Index`. Try the following:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Test",
    "app/test/{action}",
    new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" }
);
```

This will route `/app/test` to the `Index` action, and `/app/test/update` to the `Update` action.

Comment: Now I can't access the Index() action. So page load is now failing. Do I need 2 routes? one for Index and one for update()?

Comment: I get this error: Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: No, what the above route code is saying is “if there's anything after `/app/test` in the request url, call the action method in the `Test` controller with the corresponding name; if not, go to the default, `Index`”. What is the actual, complete url you are requesting to try and access the index view?